# CompareTo String Array - Works Explicitly, But Not Implicitly with Variables in Loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare elements in an array. When I use a variable within a loop, I get an out of bounds error. Yet when I use explicit values in place of the variables, with the same value, it works fine.

What am I missing?

The problem line is:

```
int result = (myList[j]).compareToIgnoreCase(myList[j + 1]);
```

But if I use this, it works (values should be identical):

```
int result = (myList[0]).compareToIgnoreCase(myList[1]);
```

Have searched high and dry for this. Other posters had different issues. Would appreciate any input! Here's the example with dummy content:

```
public class methodSortTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Create and load data into array
        String[] myList = new String[2];
        myList[0] = "Charlie";
        myList[1] = "Bravo";

        // Compare, positive/negative
        for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++)
        { 
            int result = (myList[j]).compareToIgnoreCase(myList[j + 1]);
            System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
        }
     } 
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen to `j` when you're on the last element and you add 1 to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
change this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++)
```

to this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < myList.length-1; j++)
```

problem is inside this statement:

```
int result = (myList[j]).compareToIgnoreCase(myList[j + 1]);
```

because you are accessing the `j+1`

**Simple Helping material:**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-array-indexoutofbounds-exception-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

When j equals 1, `myList[j + 1]` evaluates to `myList[2]` which throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  There is no item at index 2 because you have only inserted items at index 0 and 1.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Change your for loop from

```
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.length; j++)
```

To

```
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.length-1; j++)  // note the "-1"
```